# How to hide underline when disabled in mat-select angular

Tags: angular, list, dropdown, underline

In this page https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview , in "Disabling the select or individual options", the mat-select looks like this when is disabled:

[mat-select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eniig.png)

So I want to hide that pointed underline.

I tried a few solutions found here but none of those helped me.

Comment: .mat-form-field-disabled .mat-form-field-underline {
    background: none !important;
} ???

Comment: @Eliseo doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not underline, its a background image. Try this.

```
.mat-form-field-disabled .mat-form-field-underline {
            background-image: unset;
}
```

add it in `style.css` and check in the `angular.json` if `style.css` is loaded before the theme file

Answer (score -1):

Add this CSS code to your component :

```
:host /deep/ .mat-form-field-disabled .mat-form-field-underline {
 background-image: none !important;
}
```